# why "this" works inside render() but not on other function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, this

I currently learnign React. I was introduced to a problem with "this" keyword. Basically i understand how it works but in react or maybe in ES6 class i m finding my self confused. For example i have the below class **SearchBar** with a method **onFormSubmit**. If i try to **console.log(this.state.term)** inside this method it will throw an error of **undefined property**. *I know how to solve this error (arrow functions,bind,etc.) and that is not my problem*. My problem is that i dont understand why it is not working on OnFormSubmit() method but it will work if i console.log(this.state.term) in render() method.

```
import React from 'react';

class SearchBar extends React.Component {

    state = {term: ''};

    onFormSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state.term); //here is the error "cannot read of undefined property"
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="ui segment">
                <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} className="ui form">
                    <div className="field">
                        <label>Image Search</label>
                        <input 
                            type="text" 
                            value={this.state.term}
                            onChange={(e) => this.setState({term: e.target.value})}
                        />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

Comment: `this` is quite special in JavaScript